# Laravel 5 - Custom Package "Class Not Found" When Pushed to Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a custom package to work when deploying my Laravel app to Heroku. It works fine locally, but when pushed I get the following error:

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208: Class 'totalWebConnections\simpleBlog\simpleBlogServiceProvider' not found
```

It looks like the server is correctly loading the package from my composer file, just above the error in the log:

```
Installing totalwebconnections/simple-blog (1.0.0)
```

In my composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "totalwebconnections/simple-blog": "1.0.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "totalWebConnections\\simpleBlog\\": "vendor/totalWebConnections/simple-blog/src/"

        }
    },
```

And then in my app.php

```
    totalWebConnections\simpleBlog\simpleBlogServiceProvider::class,
```

I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: Could you check wether the server is using a different php version or not?

Comment: @utdev Both local and Heroku are running 7.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should double check your namespaces and case of file names - when you deploy on Windows for example it doesn't care whether it's simpleBlog or SimpleBog but when deployed to Linux server it won't work if it's not 100% same as it should be.

Comment: Just hit this same thing with this library - https://github.com/vhx/vhx-php -- `use VHX\API;` worked in my local Vagrant VM, but not on Heroku. Should have been `use VHX\Api;` per the docs.